IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.4 (Ultimate Edition: Working on different projects in the same window
Intellij not asking whether to open project in same window or different window.
I have IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.4 (Ultimate Edition)
When I try to open recent project it does not ask whether to open project in same window or different window. How do I enable this?

It is in Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings under Project. Set it to Ask.

